# hg pull is not happening

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to pull changes from the live server. when i give "hg pull" command, it keeps on blinking without pulling anything....

Here are the details:

os - server-fedora linux,client windows xp and the message shown was running

```
E:\putty\PLINK.EXE" -ssh -i "D:\putty-keys\foldername\rprivate.ppk" -C -agent myname@servername.domain.com "hg -R /mnt/www/serverfolder serve --stdio
```

I have updated the version to 1.7.2, no change.

Comment: If you're using Windows, a common cause is the RSA fingerprint not being stored; try pressing Ctrl+C and see if you get any message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a lot more context:

- hg version (on server and client)
- Os (on server and client)
- trace and debug if available (try a "`hg --pull --verbose`" for instance)

Such a behavior was once common with a [Kiln server](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/kiln-hangs-requires-iis-reset), where you could observe:

```
c:\Repo\Project>hg pull
_   <-- (blinks)
```

But it has been fixed since.

The was a long thread with [hg 1.5.2 (your version) stalling on Hg pull](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/hg-pull-stalls-td807413.html), but not with the same symptom.
It is worth a try though to upgrade your client first (since you may not have the possibility to do so on the server), and see if the problem persists with a more recent Hg version ([like 1.7.2](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)).

Comment: hg versions(server-1.5.2,client-1.5.2)

Comment: os - server-fedora linux,client windows xp and the message shown was running ""E:\putty\PLINK.EXE" -ssh -i "D:\putty-keys\foldername\rprivate.ppk" -C
 -agent myname@servername.domain.com "hg -R /mnt/www/serverfolder serve --stdio""

Comment: @glaze24: great informations: could you edit your question with those? That would stop the"close" vote that other users are currently putting on said question.